# Annotation as symbols on a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want heatmap annotation as symbols. '*' at place of 1 and blank at 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,0]})
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=1)
sns.heatmap(x, cmap="BuPu",annot=True,fmt='g',annot_kws={'size':10},ax=ax, yticklabels=[], cbar=False, linewidths=.5,robust=True, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heatmap can only annotate with numbers. To put other text (or unicode symbols), `ax.text` can be used. The center of each cell is at 0.5 added to both the row and the column number.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 1, 0], 'b': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 0, 0]})
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=1)
sns.heatmap(x, cmap="BuPu", annot=False, ax=ax, yticklabels=[], cbar=False, linewidths=.5)

for i, c in enumerate(x.columns):
    for j, v in enumerate(x[c]):
        if v == 1:
            ax.text(i + 0.5, j + 0.5, '★', color='gold', size=20, ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]